# Python, use scipy.ndimage affine_transform to zoom out

Tags: python, scipy, zooming, ndimage

I'm currently using affine_transform to zoom in on an image

```
s = 0.005
frame = nd.affine_transform(frame, [1-s,1-s,1],[h*s/2,w*s/2,0], order=1)
```

Now, my question is how to zoom out? I tried scaling using multiplication `[h*s*2,w*s*2,0]` instead of division (`[h*s/2,w*s/2,0]`), but instead of zooming out it pushes the image upwards and to the left.

Comment: Do you have to use `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform`, have you tried `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom`?

Comment: Try `[1+s, 1+s, 1]` or `[1/(1-s), 1/(1-s), 1]` but don't touch the `offset` argument.